# If a given # is $70$% of $X$. How do you determine what $X$ is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

Given I have the number $50,000$ which is $70$% of $X$. How do I calculate what $X$ is without guessing.

Thanks

Comment: Since $0.7 \times X = 50000$, we have that $X = \frac{50000}{0.7}$.

Comment: @eigenchris I posted my answer simultaneously to your comment. Comments like yours are something I really don't get about this site, though. Your comment is an answer, so why didn't you post it as one?

Comment: @MikeHaskel I guess you're right, it should be an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is much more natural to solve such questions without any use of variables. If $50000$ is seventy percent then one percent is $50000/70$, and so one hundred percent is $100\cdot 50000/70$. That's how I learned it in school, years before I had heard about equations and variables. That's how I do it to this day.

Answer (score 1):

We have $0.7 * X = 50,000$, so $X = \frac{50,000}{0.7} \approx 71,428.57$.

Answer (score 1):

Since, $70\%=0.70$, you may write
$$
0.70\times X=50,000
$$ and then solve it.